# twenty thirteen header size

Tags: header-image

I am new to wordpress so I am really sorry for asking such silly question.
I just want to know that where is the css of header image.
I checked in style.css but there is no css of header image.
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your theme's files will be located in your 'wp-content/themes directory'. The file you are looking for is your 'header.php'. [This](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-twenty-thirteen-header-image-size) might help to solve your problem.

Comment: WPSE have no control on external links. If you need to refer to external links in an answer, always add a few lines relevant code with a brief description to the link. If a link is removed in future, the answer will still be useful to others, even when the link is 'dead. Just remember that in future